# Select if comma separated string contains a value

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, csv

I have table

```
raw TABLE 
=========
id             class_ids
------------------------
1              1234,12334,12341,1228
2              12281,12341,12283 
3              1234,34221,31233,43434,1123
```

How to define regex to select raws if class_ids contains special id.
If we select raws with `'1234'` in class_ids result list should not contain raws with  `'12341'` in class_ids.

IDs   in column `class_ids` separated with `,`

```
SELECT FROM raw re WHERE re.class_ids LIKE (regex)
```

Answer (score 7):

#### You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column.

---

However, this is better done using string_to_array() in Postgres instead of a regex:

```
SELECT *
FROM raw 
WHERE '1234'= any(string_to_array(class_ids, ','));
```

---

If you really want to de-normalize your data, it's better to store those numbers in a proper integer array, instead of comma separated list of strings

Comment: I know, but the scheme is alrady defined and i can not change it

Answer (score 5):

A simple way uses `like`:

```
where ',' || re.class_ids || ',' like '%,1234,%'
```

However, this is not the real issue.  You should not be storing lists of ids in a string.  The SQLish way of storing them would have a table with one row per `id` and one row per `class_id`.  This is called a *junction* table.

Even if you don't use a separate table, you should at least use Postgres's built-in mechanisms, such as an array.  However, a separate table is much the preferred method, because you can explicitly declare foreign key relationships.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do this with regular expressions, you can use the `~` operator:

```
SELECT FROM raw re WHERE re.class_ids ~ '^(^|,)1234(,|$)$';
```

But I prefer a_horse_with_no_name's answer that uses arrays.